# Trying to inject a stack navigator into a component and getting error stating "you should only render one navigator"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a case where a feature contains a FlatList full of information, a search bar, sort button, and filter button.

For the sort and filter buttons I need to pull up a modal from the bottom that takes up half the screen.

I understand that React Navigation wants us to only create one 'root' navigator and all other navigators be dependents; however, in this particular case I would very much like to explicitly add a navigator to this page where a user presses on the filter button, brings up the modal, presses a filter option and then have the modal navigate to another filter subpage within the confines of its view, while maintaining the main page content and root navigation state in the background.

I remember implementing this in React Navigation V1.x, but does anyone know how to get around this in V2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Rather than doing it with nested stack navigator and things, I've implemented your requirement using built-in react native [modal](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal).

**App**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { MainScreen } from './src/screens/MainScreen';

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MainScreen
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }
);

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootStack />
    );
  }
}
```

**MainScreen**

```
import { default as React, PureComponent } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, Alert, Modal } from 'react-native';

interface Props {

}

interface States {
    num: number;
    isFilterOneVisible: boolean;
    isFilterTwoVisible: boolean;
}

export class MainScreen extends PureComponent<Props, States> {

    state = {
        num: 0,
        isFilterOneVisible: false,
        isFilterTwoVisible: false
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                flex={1}
                justifyContent={'space-evenly'}
                alignItems={'center'}
            >
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 50 }}>{this.state.num}</Text>

                <Button
                    title={'CHANGE STATE'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState((prevState: States) => ({
                            num: prevState.num + 1
                        }));
                    }}
                />


                {/* Search */}
                <Button
                    title={'Search'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        Alert.alert('Search', 'Search clicked');
                    }}
                />

                {/* Sort*/}
                <Button
                    title={'Sort'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        Alert.alert('Sort Clicked', 'Sort clicked')
                    }}
                />


                <Button
                    title={'Filter'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            isFilterOneVisible: true
                        })
                    }}
                />

                {/* Filter Modal 1*/}
                <Modal
                    visible={this.state.isFilterOneVisible}
                    transparent={true}
                    animationType={'slide'}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            isFilterOneVisible: false
                        })
                    }}
                >
                    <View
                        flex={1}
                        justifyContent={'flex-end'}
                        backgroundColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'}
                    >
                        {/* Bottom */}
                        <View
                            justifyContent={'center'}
                            alignItems={'center'}
                            backgroundColor={'white'}
                            height={200}
                        >
                            <Button
                                title={'GO TO NEXT FILTER STATE'}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        isFilterOneVisible: false,
                                        isFilterTwoVisible: true
                                    })
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>


                    </View>
                </Modal>

                {/* Filter Modal Two */}
                <Modal
                    visible={this.state.isFilterTwoVisible}
                    transparent={true}
                    animationType={'slide'}
                    onRequestClose={() => {
                        this.setState({
                            isFilterTwoVisible: false
                        })
                    }}
                >
                    <View
                        flex={1}
                        justifyContent={'flex-end'}
                        backgroundColor={'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'}
                    >
                        {/* Bottom */}
                        <View
                            justifyContent={'center'}
                            alignItems={'center'}
                            backgroundColor={'white'}
                            height={200}
                        >
                            <Button
                                title={'SET DATA AS 1000'}
                                onPress={() => {
                                    this.setState({
                                        isFilterTwoVisible: false,
                                        num: 1000
                                    })
                                }}
                            />
                        </View>


                    </View>
                </Modal>



            </ View >
        );
    }
}
```

NOTE: The code is not optimised and follows some bad patterns like `arrow-methods-in-jsx`. This is just a suggestion with a working example. Feel free to enhance the code and follow the `divide-and-conquer` strategy ;) . The full source code can be found from [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LrHeGHb0ljy9OYBTCkCdK7ve34ze9tx5)

Comment: Thanks man, I did end up going with RN modal and a horizontal paging ScrollView. Thanks for the detailed response!